# buildozer show me ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I am trying to use chatterbot and kivy.
I tried to google search but without success.
I created this main.py file

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
chatbot = ChatBot('Ron Obvious')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        resp = str(chatbot.get_response("ciao come stai?"))
        return Button(text=resp)

TestApp().run()
```

and it works on my computer. I generate the apk for my android smartphone with:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

As soon as I open it it closes. so using the command:

```
adb logcat | grep python
```

I found that:

```
05-19 18:12:18.526 17276 17309 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last):
05-19 18:12:18.526 17276 17309 I python  :   File "/media/mezzo/4345727E5C539F3E/Dropbox/Home/Scrivania/app/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
05-19 18:12:18.527 17276 17309 I python  : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot'
05-19 18:12:18.527 17276 17309 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

how can i fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mention the requirement in buildozer.spec in home directory.

`requirements = python3,chatterbot`